# How to Automate gpg?

Tags: bash, encryption, gnupg

I am using gpg in the Bash shell on Ubuntu 14.04.  I am trying to automate the password input when encrypting and decrypting large chunks of files.  I have a long string of

```
gpg -c Filename.doc
```

but for every one of those lines I am prompted for a password. How do I solve this (in simple terms please)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pull up gpg's man page, you'll see that there are helpful command-line options:

**`--passphrase-file file`** reads the passphrase from a file

**`--passphrase string`** uses **`string`** as the passphrase

You'll also want to add **`--batch`**, which prevents gpg from using interactive commands, and **`--no-tty`**, which makes sure that the terminal isn't used for any output.

Please keep in mind that using these options is a security risk.  If the passphrase is in a file, then a hacker could get to it.  If the passphrase is being supplied to a script, then there are ways a hacker could intercept it.  So please study the security implications, and don't use these options lightly.

Comment: Ok, I ran a line to test it and I was given the message "usage: gpg options --symetric [filename]" My line was as follows, what have I done wrong?               gpg filename.doc.gpg --passphrase string

Comment: You'll need to learn how to use the documentation to get along on the Linux command line.  Use `man gpg` for the complete version, which can be long and hard to read, or use a search engine to find one of the many web pages with cheat-sheet-style documentation.  You need something like `gpg --output filename.doc --decrypt filename.doc.gpg --passphrase "string" --batch --no-tty`, where `"string"` is your passphrase.  Leave the quotes in, in case you have spaces or special characters in your passphrase.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's ***possible*** to automate encryption by putting cleartext password strings in files, it would defeat the entire purpose for using GPG.

To just safeguard data from compromise rather then transmit it to third parties, encrypt with your ***OWN*** public key. This will make it possible to automate encryption using non-interactive script, ie:

```
gpg --batch --yes --trust-model always -r $YOURGPGPUBKEYEMAILADDRESS -e ./file.txt
```

**PLEASE NOTE**: I upload my **PUBLIC** key to the public server I want to protect data on, keeping the PRIVATE key apart from it. So no passwords or even a private key to decrypt with on that public server at risk of compromise.

Obviously if you're **NOT** using your own public key, tread carefully with the `--trust-model always` switch.